# writing python function to handle error cases while parsing a list

Tags: python, list, typeerror

going thru a tutorial on python lists,I tried to write a python function which counts the number of occurrences of words that start with a specific letter

```
def count_occurrences(p,letter):
    count = 0
    for elem in p:
        if elem[0]==letter:
            count = count+1
    return count


>>>count_occurrences(['damon','jim','dennis'],'d')
2
>>>count_occurrences(['damon','jim'],'d')
1
>>>count_occurrences([],'d')
0
```

but, if I input a list containing the wrong types,say `[1,2,3]` ,it will throw a `TypeError:'int' object is unsubscriptable` since the code  `elem[0]` is called on an int.

So,how do I handle this? should I use a `try : except` block or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an `isinstance()` condition to your `if` comdition to check the type of `elem`:

```
def count_occurrences(p,letter):
    count = 0
    for elem in p:
        if isinstance(elem,str) and elem[0]==letter: #if the first condition is true then
                                                     # only it'll check the next condition
            count = count+1
    return count
```

Answer (score 2):

Try ... except gives you lots of flexibility to work with the code, and it will be a good idea,

Check this doc [python exception handling](http://docs.python.org/utorial/errors.html)

*Exception handling provides the following advantages over ``traditional'' error management techniques:*

**separating Error Handling Code from ``regular'' one**
    provides a way to separate the details of what to do when something out-of-the-ordinary happens from the normal logical flow of the program code; 
**propagating Errors Up the Call Stack**
    lets the corrective action to be taken at a higher level. This allows the corrective action to be taken in the method that calling that one where an error occurs; 
**grouping Error Types and Error Differentiation**
    allows to create similar hierarchical structure for exception handling so groups they in logical way.

Just an Example:

```
def count_occurrences(p,letter):
    count = 0
    for elem in p:
        try:    # Put you code which can throw exception in try Block
            if elem[0]==letter:
                count = count+1
        except Exception, ex: # You can catch specific exceptions if you want over here
              print ex.message  # Handle your exception here
              #raise   # The 'raise' statement with no arguments inside an error
                       # handler tells Python to re-raise the exception with the 
                       # original traceback intact

    return count
```

Comment: Wherever possible you should avoid using bare `Exception` handling, ie. catching all `Exception` types. Rather handle what you expect to fail, and if something new creeps in you will be aware of it occuring imo.

Comment: @ChristianWitts: it's just an example, in the comment i have written you can catch specific exceptions.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide what you want from your function:

```
def count_occurrences(p,letter):
    count = 0
    for elem in p:
        if isinstance(elem, basestring):
            if elem[0]==letter:
                count = count+1
        else:
            # you could do something else here or just ignore it, but it seems
            # that your function really needs a list of strings as argument 
            # so it would be an error to call it with anything else and it should 
            # not fail silently.
            raise TypeError("String expected")
    return count
```

- Either it could ignore elements not matching the type. In that case you leave the `else`-section blank in the above example.
- You want to only accept list-of-strings as argument. In that case, the above example is completely yours and it will even raise an error if an invalid type is passed.

See the python documentation on [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance) for further help.

On a sidenote `try-except` block outside the loop could bring more performance though.

Comment: `isinstance(elem, (str,unicode))` -> `isinstance(elem, basestring)`

Comment: @astynax you're right. I looked for `base_string`, `string_base`, `BaseString` and so on cause I could not recall, but `basestring` didn't come into my mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you won't to use the `try ... except` you could do something like this:

```
if isinstance(elem[0],int): 
 { ... }
```

In that way, perharps, you can "skip" over that element.

A better solution would be test `isinstance` with the correct type and, in case of "test failure" skip the element.

So

```
if isinstance(elem,str) and elem[0]==letter:
 {...}
```

Comment: This will `TypeError` just the same, as `elem` might be unsubscriptable.

Comment: lots of other types are not subscriptable

Comment: @gnibbler: take a look at the "better solution" phrase

Answer (score 0):

More effectively written as:

```
sum(1 for i in sequence if i.startswith('d')) # or for single char i[0] == 'd'
```

If it's an invalid type, then you can either fail the operation using try/except, or filter out only the suitable type, eg:

```
sum(1 for i in sequence if isinstance(i, basestring) and i[0] == 'd')
```

Or to handle a fail because the list *should* be homogeneous:

```
   try:
       return sum(1 for i in sequence if i[0] =='d')
   except TypeError as e:
       pass # type doesn't have subscripting
   except IndexError as e:
       pass # may or may not be a str, but len() == 0
```

etc...

On a side note: using str.startswith('d') won't raise, so `''.startswith('d')` returns False.